# Flask/python order of operations with 'or'

Tags: python

I'm working to modify a [cookiecutter](https://github.com/wdm0006/cookiecutter-flask) Flask app. In it I have the following function, which is working correctly:

```
@blueprint.route("/home/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def home():
    form = LoginForm(request.form)
    # Handle logging in
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            login_user(form.user)
            flash("You are logged in.", 'success')
            redirect_url = request.args.get("next") or url_for("user.profile")
            return redirect(redirect_url)
        else:
            flash_errors(form)
    return render_extensions("public/home.html", form=form)
```

In the line:

```
redirect_url = request.args.get("next") or url_for("user.profile")
```

In the command line:

```
>>> request.args.get('next')
>>> url_for("user.profile")
'/users/profile'
>>> redirect_url
'/users/profile'
```

This is a basic question , but I'm assuming that python evaluates both request.args.get("next") and url_for("user.profile") and picks the first one that is not 'None' to assign?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), it only evaluates the second expression if the first one, when converted to `bool`, is `False`.

You can verify this yourself, by putting a `print` in each expression:

```
def good():
    print 'good()'
    return True

def bad():
    print 'bad()'
    return False
```

Then

```
good() or bad()
```

outputs:

```
good()
```

While

```
bad() or good()
```

Outputs:

```
bad()
good()
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathon, Can you tell me more about how expressions are "converted to bool"?

Comment: Exactly as if you call `bool()` on them.

Answer (score 1):

Python or evaluates the left condition first; if it's 'truthy' it returns the result of the evaluation, otherwise it returns the result of evaluating the right condition.

Most values are truthy, falsey values include None, zero, the empty string, empty lists or other empty containers.